# 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found on m1

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, react-native-cli

I switched to a new macbook with m1 chip and tried to run my project which ran successfully on my old macbook with intel processor.
At first there were errors with the `react-native-gesture-handler`, which were fixed simply by upgrading the version of the libraries. But I can’t fix the error with `React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h`, I tried all the solutions from the Internet.

The same issue is not only with this project, but with all my past projects. But I want to note that the new project `npx react-native init` starts without problems

**versions**:

- node - v18.15.0;
- ruby - 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958)
  [universal.x86_64-darwin22];
- XCode - 14.3.1 (14E300c);
- react-native - 0.70.2;
- react - 18.1.0;

The deployment target is 12.4

here is my **Podfile**:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

target 'Songs' do
    use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
    config = use_native_modules!

    # Flags change depending on the env values.
    flags = get_default_flags()
    pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true  
    pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
    # pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true

    use_react_native!(
        :path => config[:reactNativePath],
        # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
        # :production => production,
        :hermes_enabled => false,
        :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
        :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
        # An absolute path to your application root.
        :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
    )

    target 'SongsTests' do
        inherit! :complete
        # Pods for testing
    end

    post_install do |installer|
        react_native_post_install(installer)
        __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    end
end
```

I tried launching the terminal using Rosetta;
Install cocoapods via `arch -x86_64 pod install`;
Build using `.xcworkspace` and `.xcodeproj`;
Cleaned the project with these commands and tried again:

- `gem pristine --all`
- `bundle update`
- `cd ios && pod deintegrate && cd ..`
- `rm -rf node_modules`
- `rm -rf ios/build`
- `rm -rf ios/Pods/`
- `rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`
- `rm -f yarn.lock`
- `rm -f ios/Podfile.lock`

**UPD**
The build on my MacBook and on my iPhone, as well as the archive, is successful. The problem is only when building on the simulator

Comment: I didn't flag your question as `needs details or clarity`, but it needs focus. In the first paragraph, you said you got the `React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h`, and at the end of the post, you said your physical device build was correct, but the simulator fell into trouble. The `React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h` is a critical file to have a build, so how are you getting a physical build without issue? I think you wrote this post in several phases. Please go back and take a look to have a review.

Comment: @AmerllicA Yes, I can build to a physical device without any problems, but when I build to a simulator, I get this error. Xcode's intellisense shows me that this file exists. And I found this file in the Pods folder of the project. But, apparently, during the build process, Xcode cannot find this file. I can attach screenshots if needed